# Jquery Sortable Index Reverse

Tags: javascript, jquery, fabricjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using sortable with jQuery. When using Sortable it gives top-down index values.
For example:

```
 <ul id="sortable">
        <li>Item 1</li> /O.Index
        <li>Item 2</li> /1.Index
        <li>Item 3</li> /2.Index
 </ul>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
<ul id="sortable">
            <li>Item 1</li> /2.Index
            <li>Item 2</li> /1.Index
            <li>Item 3</li> /0.Index
</ul>
```

How can I reverse this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you asking to reverse your lis ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append the new ordered children using [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```js
var ulEl = $('#sortable');
ulEl.append(ulEl.children('li').get().reverse());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess it doesn't the best solution, but you can manipulate the elements in your sortable menu, by iterate the menu items:

```
var menuItems = $('#sortable').children('li');

menuItems.get().map((menuItem, index) => {
 menuItem.dataset.reverseIndex = (menuItems.length-1) - index
});
```

And the result will be:

```
<ul id="sortable">
  <li reverseIndex="2">Item 1</li>
  <li reverseIndex="1">Item 2</li>
  <li reverseIndex="0">Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Alonzo/unz43wke/8/):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
<script>
var menuItems = $('#sortable').children('li');

menuItems.get().map((menuItem, index) => {
 menuItem.dataset.reverseIndex = (menuItems.length-1) - index
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```